# Enabling jQuery Autocomplete on dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've read almost every article i could find on how to accomplish this, but i'm still failing miserably. mostly because i'm an amateur at jQuery/Javascript.

I have a website that contains one input element. I've managed to get jQuery Autocomplete working nicely on this. The problem is that when i dynamically add additional elements using the .append method, these new elements do not work with autocomplete.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aktive/r08m8vvy/

```
see jsfiddle for full code sample
```

Thankyou in advance for your help!! :)
-Dean

Comment: Thanks to everyone that commented. Some very well presented solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must bind autocomplete after adding new elements

```
$(wrapper).find('input[type=text]:last').autocomplete({
                source: availableAttributes
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/r08m8vvy/4/

Comment: Hello @dfionov, can you check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410824/autocomplete-in-jquery-with-dynamically-added-elements pls. Thanks

Comment: what if we want to fetch data as we type in in the inpute box and data supplied there ?

Comment: Has anyone managed to do this with mdb5 autocomplete?

Answer (score 5):

I actually found that a more reliable way was to bind using 'on' with the 'focus' action to init the auto complete based on the field class and destory it on exit. This way it cleans up the garbage and only inits it once you need to.

I was using it with cloning rows though and even doing deep cloning, which would clone the plus and minus buttons for the rows, it wasn't cloning the autocomplete.

```
var auto_opts = {...opts...}

$('body').on('focus', '.search_field', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete(auto_opts).on('blur', function(){$(this).autocomplete('destroy')});
    });
```

It also means that you aren't forced into using the last row because it works on the field as you focus on it

Comment: This is much easier and more generic solution that the other solutions.

Comment: This is great, but got a problem during on blur, I am getting this error ```cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'```. How should I fix this thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/r08m8vvy/2/

Give the new input an ID and call autocomplete on it. The initial autocompate call you make won't include the dynamically added inputs.

```
 $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box

 $( "input[id="+ x +"]" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableAttributes
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r08m8vvy/5/

You have to bind the autocomplete for new element

```
$(wrapper).append($('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>').find(":text").autocomplete({
    source: availableAttributes
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpler way to use autocomplete for dynamically created input fields.

```
$('body').on('focus', '.dynamic-input-class', function (e) {
 $(this).autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  delay: 500,
  source: function (request, response) {
   $.ajax( {
      url: "server side path that returns json data",
      data: { searchText: request.term},
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function( data ) {
        $("#data-success").html(data.returnedData); //returnedData is json data return from server side response
      }
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var nhlTeams = ['Atlanta', 'Boston', 'Buffalo', 'Calgary', 'Carolina', 'Chicago', 'Colorado', 'Columbus', 'Dallas', 'Detroit', 'Edmonton', 'Florida', 'Los Angeles', 'Minnesota', 'Montreal', 'Nashville', ];
        var nbaTeams = ['New Jersey', 'New Rork', 'New York', 'Ottawa', 'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix', 'Pittsburgh', 'Saint Louis', 'San Jose', 'Tampa Bay', 'Toronto Maple', 'Vancouver', 'Washington'];
        var nhl = $.map(nhlTeams, function (team) { return { value: team, data: { category: 'Section A' }}; });
        var nba = $.map(nbaTeams, function (team) { return { value: team, data: { category: 'Section B' } }; });
        var teams = nhl.concat(nba);

        // Initialize autocomplete with local lookup:
        $('body').on('focus', '.db_items', function(){
            $(this).autocomplete({
                lookup: teams,
                minChars: 1,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value);
                },
                showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',
                groupBy: 'category'
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```