# AutoComplete in jQuery with dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My requirement is to show few options when user input some characters (minimum 3) in one of input field which might be added dynamically too.

I can not load data at page loading at beginning because data is huge. There is an ajax call to get that filtered data.

The issue what I am getting is `Expected identifier` error on page loading at line# 2. So, could you please tell what is wrong with the below code?

```
$(document).on('keydown.autocomplete', 'input.searchInput', function() {                
            source: function (request, response) { // Line # 2
            var id = this.element[0].id;

            var val = $("#"+id).val();             
            $.ajax({                     
                    type : 'Get',
                    url: 'getNames.html?name=' + val,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading'); 
                        response(data);
                    },error: function(data) {
                          $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  
                    }
                  });
              },
                minLength: 3
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using another approach: initialize the autocomplete when you create the input:

```js
$(function() {

  // settings for each autocomplete
  var autocompleteOptions = {
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getNames.html",
        data: { name: request.term },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  // dynamically create an input and initialize autocomplete on it
  function addInput() {
    var $input = $("<input>", {
      name: "search",
      "class": "searchInput",
      maxlength: "20"
    });
    $input
      .appendTo("form#myForm")
      .focus()
      .autocomplete(autocompleteOptions);
  };

  // initialize autocomplete on first input
  $("input.searchInput").autocomplete(autocompleteOptions);
  $("input#addButton").click(addInput);
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
  <input id="addButton" type="button" value="Add an input" />
  <input name="search" class="searchInput" maxlength="20" />
</form>
```

[jsFiddle with AJAX](http://jsfiddle.net/v0sguupk/6/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot @Salman. I did the same approach. Forgot to post my answer here. I am doing `autocomplete` at the time of adding my new input field. Thanks again.

Comment: @Salman A: I wanna add data to json dynamically by call a PageMethod. The result is data (that use for autocomplete function). How can I ? Thanks.

Comment: $input is undefined coming

Comment: Well done, the idea of creating a variable with the autocomplete options is helpful to control many autocompletes (especially different types on the same page) Thanks @Salman

Answer (score 0):

The method where I am adding new input field there writing below code.

```
  function addInput(){    
      // Code to append new input filed next to existing one.
       $("table").find('input[id=clientId]:last').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var id = this.element[0].id;

                var val = $("#"+id).val();
                $.ajax({                     
                     type : 'Get',
                     url: 'getName.html?name=' + val,
                     success: function(data) {
                       var id = $(this).attr('id');
                       $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                       response(data);
                   },
                   error: function(data) {
                       $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  
                   }
               });
            },
            minLength: 3
        }); 
}
```

And some where in other js which will be used to all other (static) input fields below code is used.

```
   jQuery("input.searchInput").autocomplete({               
        source: function (request, response) {
                    var id = this.element[0].id;                        
                    var val = $("#"+id).val();
                    $.ajax({                     
                         type : 'Get',
                         url: 'getName.html?name=' + val,
                         success: function(data) {
                           var id = $(this).attr('id');
                           $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                           response(data);
                       },
                       error: function(data) {
                           $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  
                       }
                  });
               },
          minLength: 3
    });
```

Note :- For any autocomplete requests in dynamically added input fields, AutoComplete code of addInput() function will be called.

Thanks to @Salman and this post [Enabling jQuery Autocomplete on dynamically created input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498602/enabling-jquery-autocomplete-on-dynamically-created-input-fields) to give me an idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
  $("#autocompleteElement").autocomplete({
        source:function (data, response) {

            $ajax({
                url:'your/url?name='+data.term,                 
                success:function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            })

        }
    });
```

This code based on jquery UI autocomplete.

Comment: I was using this earlier. But the problem is, this will not work for elements those will added after page load like Dynamically. It works for static elements.

Comment: You can apply same code for your dynamic element. Replace the selector with your dynamic element.