# How to bind autocomplete or keydown to dynamically created span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

*Final Update* - I'm marking this question resolved. I ended up going with [Bootstrap Suggest](https://github.com/lodev09/bootstrap-suggest) for what I needed.

*Update* - With help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410824/autocomplete-in-jquery-with-dynamically-added-elements) and some comments, I've been able to get this working with Input fields. I need some help getting it to run with `div`, `span`, or something that can take in text in-line.

I'm having trouble getting autocomplete or keydown events to trigger on dynamically created spans.

As you can see in [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x57wydjc/10/), I can bind the `click` event on the new element and it works fine, but neither the `keydown` or `autocomplete` seems to work. Does Autocomplete HAVE to be on an input field? I thought it could work on the `span` (which is the whole reason I was creating the `span` in the first place).

I've tried following existing posts (like the ones listed below) but I've had no luck.

- [How do you bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .on()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693758/how-do-you-bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-on)
- [How can I add jquery ui autocomplete to a dynamically created element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670918/how-can-i-add-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-a-dynamically-created-element)
- [Bind jQuery UI autocomplete using .live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551230/bind-jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-live)

What could I be doing wrong? Am I overlooking something obvious? I've set breakpoints in the autocomplete function and it literally never hits them

Comment: Hi, you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tk3ewvhz/) its working fine on inputs .

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @Swati. I'm now able to get it to work with inputs.

I need it to be able to flow better than a whole separate input field within the div, though. Would it be possible to create a div, span, or something that would flow in-line?

I basically need to be able to autocomplete like a social media platform does with hashtags

Comment: Then try [this](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) plugin it has autocomplete feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bootstrap-Suggest](https://github.com/lodev09/bootstrap-suggest) instead of trying roll my own.